# How to remove entities from Cesium map?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have successfully added a set of symbols as entities of a cesium viewer (map).
Now I'd like to clear all the symbols but when I try this:

```
 viewer.entities.removeAll()
```

nothing happens.

What is the right way to clear a cesium map?

Answer (score 1):

If you added the entities individually with `viewer.entities.add(...)`, then calling the function you mentioned should be the right answer.

```js
viewer.entities.removeAll()
```

However, if some of the entities were added as part of a dataSource (a collection of entities), you will have to remove either the dataSource or all of the dataSource's own entities.

Give this a try:

```js
viewer.dataSources.removeAll();
```